# PHP: How to turn from list UL / LI to text

Tags: php

I am trying to turn from UL / LI [in this address](https://www.oref.org.il/Shared/Ajax/GetAlarms.aspx?md=%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%98%D7%95%D7%95%D7%97%20%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D%20%20%D7%95%2F%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A8.&lang=he&fromDate=01.09.2019&toDate=10.09.2019) list to text.

**From This:**
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sexEL.png)

**To this:**
06.09.19 23:30 אור הנר 06.09.19 23:30 ~ שדרות, איבים

```html
    <h5 id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_alertsTitle">רשימת ההתרעות</h5>
         <ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_ulAlertsList" class="more_result">
            
                    <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_rpt_ctl00_liArea" areaCode="0" time="">
                        <span><strong>06.09.19</strong></span>
                        <span class="border"><strong>23:30</strong></span>
                        <span class="span_area">אור הנר</span>
                    </li>
                
                    <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_rpt_ctl01_liArea" areaCode="0" time="">
                        <span><strong>06.09.19</strong></span>
                        <span class="border"><strong>23:30</strong></span>
                        <span class="span_area">שדרות, איבים</span>
                    </li>
                
        </ul>
```

I try to do this in php..
thanks!!

Comment: Phew! that was a risky click.

Comment: You are trying to remove the styles?

Comment: I triyng to convert from ul list to string...

Comment: But I don't see any php in your attempt?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it

Comment: @redalert - are you using PHP to generate that output? If so, please show us the PHP code. If you're not using PHP to generate that output, then please edit your question and explain how it is generated.

Comment: I only get "Access Denied" on the URL in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = '<h5 id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_alertsTitle">רשימת ההתרעות</h5>
 <ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_ulAlertsList" class="more_result">

            <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_rpt_ctl00_liArea" areaCode="0" time="">
                <span><strong>06.09.19</strong></span>
                <span class="border"><strong>23:30</strong></span>
                <span class="span_area">אור הנר</span>
            </li>

            <li id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAlarmsGrid_rpt_ctl01_liArea" areaCode="0" time="">
                <span><strong>06.09.19</strong></span>
                <span class="border"><strong>23:30</strong></span>
                <span class="span_area">שדרות, איבים</span>
            </li>

</ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $node)
{
    echo $node->textContent . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I meant I wanted to turn this into a text like this: 06.09.19 23:30 אור הנר 06.09.19 23:30 ~ שדרות, איבים

Comment: text from `h5` is not removed `רשימת ההתרעות`

Comment: It is possible to separate them with ~ ?

Comment: replace PHP_EOL with '~'

Comment: Why is the coding displayed like this: 06.09.19 23:30 ×××¨ ×× ×¨ ??